# Hidden Products In One Category

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

There is something wrong on **one of my category**.. the products are suddenly **hidden** in **frond-end**.

i can see them in admin panel; i can see the product profile pages on frontend, there are enough stocks/global store..
Everything was ok about an hour ago (i was adding new products; but didnt change anything)

don't know what happened; but now, there is no product listing on one of my category and its subcategories. **(no problem in other categories)**.

i tried everything like,

```
indexer:reindex
cache:clean
cache:flush
setup:static-content:deploy
```

etc...

what do you suggest me? (my magento is 2.1.0)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your product visibity, it should be either 'catalog,search' or 'catalog' to show product on listing page.
2. Check your display mode of category, it should be 'product only' or 'static block and product'